# Kubernetes on GKE can't mount volumes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

There are two nodes and 2 pods running in my cluster
 (1 pod on each node)
My persistent volume claim is below

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: blockchain-data
  annotations: {
        "volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class": "blockchain-disk"
    }
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ssd
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Gi
```

and `mystorageclass`

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: blockchain-disk
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

and I mounted it on my container like this

```
spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/indiesquare-dev/geth-node:v1.8.12
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: geth-node
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts:
            - name: blockchain-data
              mountPath: /root/.ethereum
      volumes:
        - name: blockchain-data
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: blockchain-data
```

I have replicas set to 2. When start the deployment, the first pod starts correctly with the disk properly mounted.

However, the second pod gets stuck at `containtercreating`

If I run `kubectl describe pods`

```
Warning  FailedAttachVolume     18m               attachdetach-controller                       Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-c56fbb79-954f-11e8-870b-4201ac100003" Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another
```

I think according to this message, I am trying to attach the disk which is already attached to another node.

What I want to do is to have two persistent volumes separately attached to two pods. If the pods scale up, then each should have a different volume attached.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't attach a GCE Persistent Disk to multiple nodes. So if your pods are landing on different nodes you can't reuse the same disk.

You need something like `ReadOnlyMany`  access mode but you have ReadWriteOnce.

Read https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes